# MVVM - UI related code in View model - true separation of concerns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I started implementing a MVVM design pattern in an existing WPF c# application. I am completely new and have never used design patterns or dependency injection before. I was looking at the frameworks already available and have adopted MVVM light. I moved the logic from the view to the viewmodel. I have lot of code in the `PopulateTestMenu` which is related to UI in the view model. It also has calls to the event handlers. How do I take care of this?

In the **XAML** I have:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Menu>
       <MenuItem Header="Load All History..." Command="{Binding LoadAllHistory}">
```

In the **MainViewModel** class I have:

```
public ICommand LoadAllHistory { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{            
    LoadAllHistory = new RelayCommand(() => LoadHistoryExecute(), () => true);
}
```

The code that I moved from my **view** to the **viewmodel**:

```
private void LoadHistoryExecute()
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Test History File (*.xml)|*.xml";
        ofd.Title = "Open Test History";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LoadTestHistoryCallback, ofd.FileNames);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
       //some code
    }
}

private void LoadTestHistoryCallback(object state)
{
    try
    {
        string[] fileNames = (string[])state;

        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            bool success = MyApp.Instance.ParseTestHistory(fileName);
            string status = success
                          ? String.Format("'{0}' loaded successfully.",      
               System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName))
                          : String.Format("Failed to load history from '{0}'.",    
               System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
            {
                Status = status;
            });
            PopulateTestMenu(new SortedList<int, int>());
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //some code
    }
}

private void PopulateTestMenu(SortedList<int, int> indexes)
{
    try
    {
        _testMenuMutex.WaitOne();

        //Populate the Tests menu with the list of tests.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
        {
            menuTests.Items.Clear();
            var checkEventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(testMenuItem_Checked);
            bool added = false;

            if (MyApp.Instance.TestHistory != null && 
               MyApp.Instance.TestHistory.Count > 0)
            {
                List<ushort> subIds = new 
                   List<ushort>MyApp.Instance.TestHistory.Keys);

                foreach (ushort subId in subIds)
                {
                   MenuItem menuItem = null;
                    menuItem = new MenuItem();
                    menuItem.Header = subId.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');**

                    MenuItem none = new MenuItem();
                    none.Header = "None";
                    none.IsCheckable = true;
                    none.IsChecked = true;
                    none.Checked += checkEventHandler;
                    none.Unchecked += checkEventHandler;

                    menuItem.Items.Add(none);

                    if (MyApp.Instance.TestHistory != null && 
                       MyApp.Instance.TestHistory.ContainsKey(subId))
                    {
                        var tests = MyApp.Instance.TestHistory[subId];

                        if (tests != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Test t in tests)
                            {
                                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                                item.IsCheckable = true;

                                string description = t.Description.Replace("\n", 
                                "\n".PadRight(34, ' '));
                                string header = abc;
                                item.Header = header;
                                item.DataContext = t;
                                item.Checked += checkEventHandler;
                                item.Unchecked += checkEventHandler;
                                menuItem.Items.Add(item);
                            }
                            if (tests.Count > 0)
                            {
                                menuTests.Items.Add(menuItem);
                                added = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Carry over the previous selection.
                    if (indexes.ContainsKey(subId) && indexes[subId] > -1)
                    {                            ((MenuItem)menuItem.Items[indexes[subId]]).IsChecked = 
                         true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: look into Item binding, you could just bind to a list of items instead of populating menu in one by one

Comment: No.  A VM would not be creating MenuItems because it breaks the abstraction  principle and deals with concrete objects on the UI surface.  The VM instead can create the collection of items which is bound to the menu.  Create a menu in Xaml and bind its ItemsSource property to a collection!

Answer (score 2):

I am still trying to figure out what you are asking =)...

But you are mixing up some things... Remember one of the core concepts of MVVM is to make the viewmodel testable and remove all view related code off from the viewmodel. So no dependencies to WPF at all. So `MenuItem` looks like a WPF `MenuItem` and should not be in your `ViewModel`.

Instead you could consider to make a `MenuItemViewModel` which binds to the `MenuItem` in the View. And it I could see an `ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> TestMenu` instead of your sorted list.

In your method `LoadTestHistoryCallback` you would instanciate (could be done via DI) the `MenuItemViewModel` and add it to the TestMenu Collection. The `MenuItemViewModel` could have `status` property which could be assigned from outside or internaly. (It can also have some additional logic, hey its a viewmodel).

In the `View` you could then bind it to a list with a template representing the `MenuItem` via DataBinding.

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" />
```

So remember `ViewModel` can also contain `ViewModels` or `collections` of `viewmodel`. 
Use the rich databinding api from WPF. 
Work with bindable Properties like `ObservebaleCollections` or `Properties` that are extended with `PropertyChanged` notification.

HTH

P.S: You can then have a click `ICommand` in the `MenuItemViewModel` and execute actions or better use the `EventAggregator` or `Messenger` to notify other `ViewModels` ...(but that's a story for another question =)... )

Comment: Very Helpful comments. I will create a MenuItemViewModel inside my MainViewModel and also look at how I can do itemBinding.

Comment: Glad I could help =)... if this answers your question consider to mark it as 'answerd'

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the theory of MVVM correctly by moving that code to the ViewModel however just keep in mind that the View should only provide the "structure" of the display.

What is displayed is provided by the model in the ViewModel.

With that in mind separate out the menu parts from the ViewModel method and put them in the View, but leave the Test object creation parts (Binding ViewModel objects to View structure is what it's about).

Within your PopulateTestMenu method the menus and menu structure need to be specified in the View while the data populating them needs to be created and formatted in the ViewModel.

In the View you will bind the appropriate object parts to the menu structure, and the ViewModel will automatically fill it in with the model objects when the model is bound to the view.

Looking at the code, it appears that your Test object is your ViewModel, and the Menu and MenuItem structure needs to be created in the View, then you specify the binding of the specific properties of the Test object to the specific structure parts of the Menu within the View.

Comment: when the user clicks on the menu item menuTests, the items.clear() is called and a new event handler for the testMenuItemChecked is instantiated. I wanted my view's code behind not have any event handlers. I want to bind everything using commands. Can you please explain how I can modify the code in PopulateTestMenu()  to achieve what you just said? Thank you.

Comment: @brinky -> MenuItem is in the Controls namespace.  Would you really want that dependency in a VM?

Comment: You absolutely do not want to reference a MenuItem in your view model.

Comment: Please, everyone, read my comment completely before commenting further.  The OP has taken only "the first step" in converting this code to MVVM strucure, I outlined the basic concept he needs to follow to continue the conversion.

Comment: @Asha I believe the confusion you're experiencing is due to the fact that in MVVM, you don't use the logic and events to drive the actions as in classic WPF or WinForms.  MVVM works by convention, specifically, naming convention of the Controllers, ViewModels, and Views, and model binding.  You should read up online or get a good book on WPF MVVM; it is a rather sharp paradigm shift to think in MVVM terms compared to classic usage.  A rather long-titled (but mercifully short read) is the book Building Enterprise Applications with WPF and the MVVM Pattern by Raffaele Garofalo (Microsoft Press).

Comment: And YES you need to create the Object to be bound to the view in the ViewModel, and the UI (totally) in the View.  The binding convention will tie together the proper parts of the ViewModel to the proper display area of the View.  I would start by reading up on the XAML required to create your View, and the WPF-specific controls to implement in the XAML to provide your structure....for instance, the StackPanel, ListBox, and Grid controls for WPF.

Comment: @brinky. Thanks for posting the name of the book that I should read.  I will look up online to see the how the event handlers would be replaced by MVVM conventiontionally.